# telebot, не могу из списка передать в кортеж

Tags: telebot

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему с динамической переменной.
Стандартные решение в google пробовал, не помогло.
В текстовом файле "log_hostel_2.txt" неизвестно сколько будет строчек, выглядит так "{ 5365662884 }< Александр >".
Заранее огромное спасибо.
ps. (Если что не так сделал, не пеняйте сильно, моё первое обращение куда либо.)

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
from requests import get
import re
bot=telebot.TeleBot('Ваш токен' )
def keyboard(where_call):
    kb = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    if where_call == 'start':
        kb_1_4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Чат.', callback_data='1_4_inline')
        kb.add(kb_1_4)
        return kb  
    elif where_call == 'subcategory':
        kb_2_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Вернуться.', callback_data='1_1_inline')
        kb_2_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Приватный чат.', callback_data='2_2_inline')
        kb.add(kb_2_1, kb_2_2) 
        return kb
    elif where_call == 'subcategory_2':
        spisok_chat = []    
        file_path = "log_hostel_2.txt"
        required = '<'
        with open(file_path) as file:
            for num_line, line in enumerate(file):
                if required in line:
                    text = ' '.join(re.findall(r'<([^<>]+)>', line))
                    spisok_chat.append(text)
        spisok_chat_nimber = len(spisok_chat) 
        kb_spisok = []
        zero = 0       
        while spisok_chat_nimber > 0:
            spisok_chat_nimber = spisok_chat_nimber - 1
            knopka_chat = (spisok_chat[spisok_chat_nimber]) 
            kb_spisok.append(zero)
            kb_spisok[zero] = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=knopka_chat, callback_data='1_1_inline')            
            zero = zero + 1
        kb.add(kb_spisok[0], kb_spisok[1]) # Проблема тут
        return kb
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def start(message):        
    bot.reply_to(message, "Привет!", reply_markup=keyboard('start'))
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == '1_1_inline':
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                              text="Главная.", reply_markup=keyboard('start'))     
    elif call.data == '1_4_inline':    
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                              text="Общий чат.", reply_markup=keyboard('subcategory'))  
    elif call.data == '2_2_inline':  
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                              text="Приватный чат.", reply_markup=keyboard('subcategory_2'))  
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: Собственно, в чём именно проблема? Какая ошибка выдаётся?

Comment: В текстовом файле может быть большое количество строчек. В скобках < имя >  в файл будут добавляться автоматически. Не могу ни придумать ни понять как сюда добавить заранее неизвестное количество. """""""kb.add(kb_spisok[0], kb_spisok[1])"""""""